# How to use a variable within a string inside of an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have the following function which I'll be repeating several times but changing the array values.

```
register_field_group(array (
    'id' => 'acf_page-options-cat-work',
    'title' => 'Featured Posts',
    'fields' => array (
        array (
            'key' => 'field_5262q874nq12',
            'label' => 'Featured Posts',
            'name' => 'featured_posts',
            'type' => 'repeater',
            'sub_fields' => array (
                array (
                    'key' => 'field_5262q874nq13',
                    'label' => 'Post',
                    'name' => 'featured_post',
                    'type' => 'post_object',
                    'post_type' => array (
                        0 => 'post',
                    ),
                    'allow_null' => 0,
                    'multiple' => 0
                )
            ),
            'row_min' => 0,
            'row_limit' => '',
            'layout' => 'row',
            'button_label' => 'Add a post',
        )
    )
));
```

I would like to have the `'key'` element be dynamic. I've tried using the curly braces to insert the variable like so:

```
array(
     'key' => 'string{$variable}'
)
```

but it's not working...

```
$rand_string = 'asdasdasda';

register_field_group(array (
    'id' => 'acf_page-options-cat-work',
    'title' => 'Featured Posts',
    'fields' => array (
        array (
            'key' => 'field_526{$rand_string}12',
            'label' => 'Featured Posts',
            'name' => 'featured_posts',
            'type' => 'repeater',
            'sub_fields' => array (
                array (
                    'key' => 'field_526{$rand_string}13',
                    'label' => 'Post',
                    'name' => 'featured_post',
                    'type' => 'post_object',
                    'post_type' => array (
                        0 => 'post',
                    ),
                    'allow_null' => 0,
                    'multiple' => 0
                )
            ),
            'row_min' => 0,
            'row_limit' => '',
            'layout' => 'row',
            'button_label' => 'Add a post',
        )
    )
));
```

How can I use a variable within a string inside of an array?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with double-quote

```
$cat = "meow";
$test = array(
     'key' => "string {$cat}"
);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($test);
echo "</pre>";
```

Hope it will be useful for you.